# Can't use Options props on React-select with Unform

Tags: reactjs, react-select, unform

Hey guys i'm trying to use select component with unform and in their documentation is recommended to use React-select, they recommend create my own custom Select with this code:

```
import React, { useRef, useEffect } from 'react';
import ReactSelect, {
  OptionTypeBase,
  Props as SelectProps,
} from 'react-select';
import { useField } from '@unform/core';
interface Props extends SelectProps<OptionTypeBase> {
  name: string;
}
export default function Select({ name, ...rest }: Props) {
  const selectRef = useRef(null);
  const { fieldName, defaultValue, registerField, error } = useField(name);
  useEffect(() => {
    registerField({
      name: fieldName,
      ref: selectRef.current,
      getValue: (ref: any) => {
        if (rest.isMulti) {
          if (!ref.state.value) {
            return [];
          }
          return ref.state.value.map((option: OptionTypeBase) => option.value);
        }
        if (!ref.state.value) {
          return '';
        }
        return ref.state.value.value;
      },
    });
  }, [fieldName, registerField, rest.isMulti]);
  return (
    <ReactSelect
      defaultValue={defaultValue}
      ref={selectRef}
      classNamePrefix="react-select"
      {...rest}
    />
  );
};
```

but I can't use Options props in the select component in my form and i don't know other way to put my options in the select, can you guys help me please?

Comment: Can you please explain a bit better what you mean that you can't use the Options props?

Comment: You can not use because probably they are not in same structure